# Why is XST optimizing away my registers and how do I stop it?

Tags: embedded, verilog, fpga, xilinx

I have a simple verilog program that increments a 32 bit counter, converts the number to an ASCII string using $sformat and then pushes the string to the host machine 1 byte at a time using an FTDI FT245RL.

Unfortunately Xilinx XST keeps optimizing away the string register vector.  I've tried mucking around with various initialization and access routines with no success.  I can't seem to turn off optimization, and all of the examples I find online differ very little from my initialization routines.  What am I doing wrong?

```
module counter(CK12, TXE_, WR, RD_, LED, USBD);

   input CK12;
   input TXE_;
   output WR;
   output RD_;
   output [7:0] LED;
   inout [7:0] USBD;

   reg [31:0] count = 0;

   reg [7:0] k;
   reg wrf  = 0;
   reg rd   = 1;
   reg [7:0] lbyte = 8'b00000000;   

   reg td              = 1;
   parameter MEM_SIZE  = 88;
   parameter STR_SIZE  = 11;
   reg [MEM_SIZE - 1:0] str;
   reg [7:0] strpos = 8'b00000000;

   initial
     begin
        for (k = 0; k < MEM_SIZE; k = k + 1)
          begin
             str[k]    = 0;
          end
     end

   always @(posedge CK12)
     begin
        if (TXE_ == 0 && wrf == 1)
          begin
             count    = count + 1;
             wrf         = 0;
          end


        else if (wrf == 0)  // If we've already lowered the strobe, latch the data
          begin
             if(td)
               begin
                  $sformat(str, "%0000000000d\n", count);
                  strpos = 0;
                  td     = 0;
               end

             str      = str << 8;
             wrf         = 1;
             strpos      = strpos + 1;       

             if(strpos == STR_SIZE)
               td        = 1;

          end       
     end

   assign RD_             = rd;
   assign WR              = wrf;
   assign USBD            = str[87:80];
   assign LED             = count[31:24];

endmodule
```

> Loading device for application
>   Rf_Device from file '3s100e.nph' in
>   environment /opt/Xilinx/10.1/ISE.
>   WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch str_0
>   has a constant value of 0 in block
>   . This FF/Latch will be
>   trimmed during the optimization
>   process.
>
> WARNING:Xst:1896 - Due to other
>   FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch str_1
>   has a constant value of 0 in block
>   . This FF/Latch will be
>   trimmed during the optimization
>   process.
>
> WARNING:Xst:1896 - Due to other
>   FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch str_2
>   has a constant value of 0 in block
>   . This FF/Latch will be
>   trimmed during the optimization
>   process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $sformat task is unlikely to be synthesisable - consider what hardware the compiler would need to produce to implement this function! This means your 'str' register never gets updated, so the compiler thinks it can optimize it away.  Consider a BCD counter, and maybe a lookup table to convert the BCD codes to ASCII codes.

AFAIK 'initial' blocks are not synthesisable.  To initialize flops, use a reset signal.  Memories need a 'for' loop like you have, but which triggers only after reset.

Comment: Alright!  I initially didn't understand half of what you said, but I spent the last couple of minutes looking up what a BCD is and it looks exactly like what I want.  I just need to figure out how to do the look-up table now.  I was suspicious of $sformat but the compiler didn't complain and it worked perfectly in simulation, but I guess I know now.  Thanks!

Comment: Lookup tables are easy - they're `case` statements!

In simulation, you can do anything - it'll treat the code as a program.  For stuff you want synthesised, you have to keep in mind that you're describing hardware, not programming as such.